# OpenPyXL Text Wrapping not being applied

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I understand this is very specific question but has anybody run into any problems using OpenPyXL's Text Wrapping feature? I'm applying it to each cell while iterating through a number of rows but it doesn't seem to take any effect? Feel free to make any other suggestions regarding the structure of the code.

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A2:D1000'):
    for cell in row:
        if end != True:
            cell.style.alignment.wrap_text = True
            cell.value = array[x]          
            print ("Line: " + str(x))
            x += 1
        try:
            end = array[x]
        except:
            end = True
```

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question, but I was just stuck with a similar problem so here goes.

From openpyxl 2.0 onwards styles are immutable. You'll need to create a style with the wrap text and then apply that style to the cell.

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

# create alignment style
wrap_alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
# assign
cell.alignment = wrap_alignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl is a library and not an application: in many situations you can only leave instructions for an application like Excel to follow, formatting cells is an example of this.

If you want to wrap text in Python, use the `textwrap` module.